# Sybase ASE temp table not found

Tags: sql, database, sybase, sap-ase

I have a temporary table called `table1` created like this:

`create table`**`tempdb..table1`**`(id int)`

The table was not created by the owner of the `tempdb` database.

When i tried earlier to access the table with this query, inside a stored procedure ( just for testing ):

`select top 10 * from tempdb..table1`

I got this error:

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1:
 Server 'SERVER', Procedure 'storedProcedure', Line 30:
 tempdb..table1 not found. Specify owner.objectname or use sp_help to check whether the object
 exists (sp_help may produce lots of output).
```

However, about an hour later the same stored procedure ran without any problems.

The table was not dropped and created again during that hour and I cannot find any reason for this strange behavior. I could fix this by applying some kind of naming hack, but I do not want to insert hacks into a quite sensitive flow, meaning a lot of users could drop and create the table.

I am asking if someone could explain this behavior so I can avoid it from now on.

Comment: It sounds like a fluke, since it has only happened the 1 time.  If it's really a concern have you thought about doing a check to see if the table exists before running your query?  e.g. if table exists, run query else create table.

Comment: that's the way it's done right now. but after creating the table, i couldn't access the table how it should be accessed: `tempdb..table1`

Answer (score 0):

use tempdb.owner.tablename to query. probably tempdb.guest.table1

Comment: Pardon me, but your answer is not clear (to me, at least). Are you saying that `owner` - in `temp.owner.tablename` - should be replaced with the actual owner which you are guessing to be `guest`? Also, I recommend that you learn how to use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format your posts.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).